# .htaccess redirecting secure

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

*<sub>Haven't found what i'm looking for so far.</sub>*

I want to redirect all my site visitors to the secure version of the URL they type in, so i've put this in my `.htaccess`-file.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [R,L]
```

So far so good, but now I want that visitors who type in

- `www.mywebsite.com/directory/param1/etcetera/` or
- `www.mywebsite.com/directory/file.php?param1=value1`

are being redirected to

- `https://www.mywebsite.com/directory/param1/etcetera/` or
- `https://www.mywebsite.com/directory/file.php?param1=value1`

as well, cause that isn't happening.
Can some guru help me out? :) thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first case, `www.mywebsite.com/directory/param1/etcetera/`, should be redirected to its https variant by your RewriteRule.  I can't see why that wouldn't work.

To cover the second case, in order to have Apache include the query string, you need to add the [QSA flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa), so:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [R,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Do you have `RewriteEngine on`?

Comment: yep that's on, also got some other things rewriting later on in the file, but that's not causing problems

Comment: Stray `RewriteCond` statements above?  I'm grasping at straws here...  You may need to use `RewriteLogLevel` to understand what's happening, although that's hard to do.

Comment: ok i've removed all other lines in my .htaccess, and adjusted my startpost, these 4 lines are now the only lines in my file (just to rule out everything else :-) )

Comment: Any messages in the error log?  For example it would tell you if mod_rewrite isn't enabled.

Comment: nope, just checked and error log is clean. Mod_rewrite is working.